# d3 geo Change topojson file on click/zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a world map build in D3.js
For performance's sake I am using world-atlas 110m version, but I want to increase the map detail as I zoom in.

I also want to change projection and, therefore topojson file when I click on the United States.
(That is to use geoAlbersUsa(), and render US states)

I've got some very basic functionality on changing the map projection on click, but I am struggling on how to change the topojson file.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { feature } from 'topojson';

var projections = [
  {name: "mercator", value: d3.geoMercator()},
  {name: "orthograpic", value: d3.geoOrthographic()},
  {name: "Us", value: d3.geoAlbersUsa()} ]

let projection = projections[1].value;
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const graticule = d3.geoGraticule();
let pathGenerator = d3.geoPath(projection);
let country;

const g = svg.append('g');
          

g.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'sphere')
    .attr('d', pathGenerator({type: 'Sphere'}));

g.append('path')
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", pathGenerator);

g.call(d3.drag()
.on("drag", (event, d) => {
  //if (projection === projections[1].value){
  const rotate = projection.rotate()
    const k = 75 / projection.scale()
    projection.rotate([
      rotate[0] + event.dx * k,
      rotate[1] - event.dy * k
    ])
    pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)
    svg.selectAll(".graticule").attr("d", pathGenerator)
    svg.selectAll(".country").attr("d", pathGenerator)
  //}
  //else{return}
}));

function update(){
  pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)
  svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", pathGenerator)
  svg.selectAll("path").transition().duration(750)
  svg.selectAll(".sphere").attr("d", pathGenerator({type:'Sphere'}))
    
}

Promise.all([
  d3.tsv('https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.tsv'),
  d3.json('https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json'),
  d3.json("states-albers-10m.json")
]).then(([tsvData, topoJSONdata, usTopoJson]) => {
const countryName = tsvData.reduce((accumulator, d) => { //for each..
    accumulator[d.iso_n3] = d.name;
    return accumulator;
  })

const countries = feature(topoJSONdata, topoJSONdata.objects.countries);
  console.log(projection)
g.selectAll('.country').data(countries.features)
    .enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'country')
      .attr('d', pathGenerator)
      .on("click", function(event,d) {
        country = countryName[d.id];
        if(country === "United States" && projection !== projections[0].value){
          console.log(projection);
          projection = projections[0].value
          update();
        }
        else{
          projection = projections[1].value
          update();
        }
      })
})

g.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', (event) => {
  g.attr('transform', event.transform, )
}))
```

LIVE DEMO: https://vizhub.com/Glebenator/810613a0a8584310abdcbcdaa78a368a

Comment: I am new to d3, and most tutorials out there are for about 4 version behind, so any suggestions on how I can imporove the existing code are welcome:)

Comment: It looks like there are two discrete questions here: changing projection with zoom and changing geographic data source with zoom. If I had to choose, I'd say you're more interested in the 2nd question, is that right?

Comment: 2nd question yes, though the zoom part is not that imporant. It could just be a simple onClick.

Comment: Sorry, meant to come back to this sooner - been busy lately. Will look this afternoon.

Comment: No worries, thanks for looking into it.
I am thinking of somehow reading the current zoom scale, and calling some sort of render function with different data after a certain zoom level

Comment: That's along the lines I was thinking you were looking for - had started when you commented - got side tracked momentarily. Hope the below is somewhat useful - there are lots of different angles that could be explored here. This sort of thing is where vector layers offer a lot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change features/data source/whatever with zoom, you'll need to get the current zoom state, which is contained in the the event passed to the zoom event listener (or d3.event before d3 v6).

This gives us a relatively easy zoom listener:

```
 .on("zoom", function(event) {

   // if zoomed in sufficiently:
   if(event.transform.k > 4) {
     /*  draw the detailed features */
   }
   // otherwise:
   else {
    /* draw the undetailed features */
   }
   // update the paths:      
   features.attr("d",path)
 })
```

Below I combine this with some semantic zooming, with which you can more easily apply a projection clip extent, which will stop the path generator from drawing features outside of the desired extent. It'll still project their points, but doesn't have to draw them. There are other ways to get performance gains, but I'll leave them for another day. The semantic zoom uses the zoom's translate and the original projection translate (the latter needs to be scaled by the zoom scale), and combines the zoom and projection scales:

```
  projection.translate([t.x+240*t.k,t.y+120*t.k]).scale(baseScale*t.k);
```

My example below is not fancy in how it loads data, it loads a base layer, and then it loads a more detailed file. Once the more detailed file loads, it applies a zoom behavior that allows you to zoom into a more detailed feature set (continents vs countries). There are lots of ways you might want to do this and my example is merely demonstrative.

For an optimization, you could see if the zoom level has crossed a threshold by storing the previous zoom value and only calling an re-render/update function if the new value has crossed a threshold.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 480)
  .attr("height", 240);
  
var baseScale = 480/Math.PI/2;  
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .scale(baseScale)
  .translate([240,120])
  .clipExtent([[0,0],[480,240]])
 
  
var path = d3.geoPath(projection);
  
d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/land-110m.json").then(function(land) {

   // draw world initially:
   var world = topojson.feature(land, land.objects.land);
   
   var features = update([world]).attr("d",path);

   d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json").then(function(countries) {
   
   // get a more detailed set of features:
   var detail = topojson.feature(countries, countries.objects.countries).features;
   
   // apply a zoom behavior:
   var zoom = d3.zoom()
     .on("zoom", function(event) {
      var t = event.transform;
      
      // Semantic zoom using the projection:
      projection.translate([t.x+240*t.k,t.y+120*t.k]).scale(baseScale*t.k);
      
      // if zoomed in sufficiently:
      if(t.k > 1) {
        // draw the detailed features:
        features = update(detail);
      }
      // otherwise:
      else {
        // draw the undetailed features:
        features = update([world]);
      }
      // update the paths:      
      features.attr("d",path)
     })
    svg.call(zoom);

   })
})

function update(data) {
  return svg.selectAll("path").data(data).join("path");
}
```

```css
path {
 stroke-width: 1px;
 stroke: black;
 fill: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/3.0.2/topojson.min.js"></script>
```